# java mandatory package declaration

Tags: java, package

In java, why is it mandatory for each class to declare the package it belongs to. I mean, package hierachy is already described/enforced using the folder
structure of the file system. It looks to me that the line:

```
package com.mypackage;
```

As the first line of each class is somehow a redundant information. But I'm pretty sure there's a good reason for it to be there.

Comment: Probably the whole folder structure is redundant - I don't know, but I would expect the compiler to look inside the files for the package name and not traversing the folder tree as that might be really slow, when you have a large project with 1000's of classes and packages.

Comment: Why do you think the `package` is mandatory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I mean, package hierachy is already described/enforced using the folder structure of the file system.

Not necessarily. While it's certainly a good idea to organize your code that way, it's not a requirement. Also bear in mind that source code needn't be in a file system to start with.

Fundamentally, I think it's entirely reasonable to make the *content* of the source file the important thing. Heck, you could take it to the other extreme and assume the class being declared by the filename - that's not just a convention, but one which is explicitly valid (in the JLS) to be enforced by the compiler for public top-level classes.

Comment: So you are fundamentally saying that, JLS allows you to put all of your classes in a single file or in a single directory, this way, given a compliant compiler, package delcarations would not be redundant at all ?

Comment: @GionJh: Yup, absolutely. Try it - put lots of Java files with different packages in the same directory, run `javac -d . *.java` and you'll find that the package structure will be created for the *class* files, but it doesn't need to be in the source files. On the other hand, the compiler will look for classes it hasn't been told about the source file for using the directory structure.

Comment: Can you explain further the second part of your comment: "the compiler will look for classes it hasn't been told about the source file for using the directory structure" ? thanks for your time.

Comment: @GionJh: If you compile just `A.java`, but that references a class called `B`, the compiler will try to find `B` either as a class on the classpath, or `B.java` in the source path, using your imports to work out where to look.